# How to verify a users password for root privledges in python

Tags: python, linux, passwords, python-2.x

I'm attempting to write a python program that requires a the users password to run some external commands using the `subprocess` libraries. The code is going to look roughly like this.

```
import subprocess

passwordInput = raw_input("What is your password: ")

subprocess.call('echo ' + passwordInput + ' | sudo -S pacman -Syy', shell=True)
```

This program works fine, however if you enter the incorrect password, the program fails. How would I go about adding some kind of error proofing to detect if the password is entered incorrectly?

I was thinking perhaps wrapping this code in a `while` loop and then using a `try-except` to test the password, however I'm not sure what kind of `except` could do this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why not add that program/user combo in the sudoers file and go home early?

Comment: Won't the "echo password" show up in ps -ef? If yes, it's a bit of a security issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just ditch the `echo`.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['sudo', '-S', 'pacman', '-Syy'])
```

The `sudo` program will ask the user a certain number of times.  There's no need for your Python program to know the user's password.  Ever.

Another concern is that you are using `shell=True`, which means that if my password is `$nakel0ver` because I love snakes, your program will pass an empty password to `sudo`.

Comment: Well, I'm going to be porting this code to a GUI frontend that runs on first boot, so the user won't be able to type into a terminal, its going to be inputed through a GUI.

Comment: @josh: Then use `gksudo` or something.

Comment: Yes, `gksudo` is the way to go.

Comment: The whole program should not be ran as root the whole time, otherwise I would just use gksudo. I really would prefer to have some code like I described in my post, due to many reasons that would be somewhat hard to explain without explaining the entire purpose of the program.

Comment: josh: That is a mistake.  Do not store the password in a long-running process so you can run sudo.  If necessary, run a daemon as root and forward commands to it.  But I repeat, **do not store the user's password in your process**.

Comment: I'm writing a screensaver. I need to know the user's password.