# Validated `su` password in python accepted by user

Tags: python, linux, operating-system, ubuntu-16.04

I want to validate root password which is entered by user script which is used to install the driver which requires root.
if I try to run that installer as a `sudo` or `superuser privilege` it gives below Error:

```
ERROR: installer must be run as root
```

I am accepting the password with the help of `getpass()` method at the beginning of a script and will use that password in between the execution of it so don't want to make a user wait for such long time.

I found [what-is-the-best-way-for-checking-if-the-user-of-a-script-has-root-like-privileg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806897/what-is-the-best-way-for-checking-if-the-user-of-a-script-has-root-like-privileg/20153881#20153881) and [how-to-verify-a-users-password-for-root-privledges-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928103/how-to-verify-a-users-password-for-root-privledges-in-python) but this will check validation of sudo password not the `root`.
I want to check password is valid for root login.

How Should I validate that `user entered the password` is correct for `root` using python?

As well as My knowledge is a concern I have to check the validity of root password by performing so `su` operation

we can not run the whole script as a root as after installation script is going to run some test as a normal user.

Comment: Possibly helpful or related: [How to verify a users password for root privledges in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928103/how-to-verify-a-users-password-for-root-privledges-in-python)

Comment: @davedwards is this also for sudo only not for root

Comment: yes, you are correct, but because you don't want run the script as a normal user (not `root` user) you will want to give that normal user `sudo` privileges and run the script using the user's "sudo" password, not `root` user with `root` password. Is that right?

Comment: giving root privileges to some user will not work, installer requires root to install

Comment: a user running as `sudo` is same as running as `root`. See: [Sudo vs root; any actual differences?](https://superuser.com/questions/771500/sudo-vs-root-any-actual-differences)

Comment: No both are different thing

Comment: @AmanJaiswal they are - or, you cannot gain more capabilities to an existing process

Comment: As soon as you accept the password perform a `sudo ls &>/dev/null`. The command will fail if the password is incorrect.

Comment: @jww I need to validate password of ``su` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading multiple stuff somehow I figure out that we can authenticate root password via a Python script. Below is My approach to Authenticate the Same.

```
import subprocess
import getpass
FAIL = 'Password: \r\nsu: Authentication failure'

def validate_pass(passwd):
    ret = 0
    try:
        cmd = '{ sleep 1; echo "%s"; } | script -q -c "su -l root -c ls /root" /dev/null' % passwd
        ret = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
        return ret
    except:
        return 1



passwd = getpass.getpass(prompt='Password: ', stream=None)
res = validate_pass(passwd).strip()
if FAIL == res:
    print(res)
    print ("Invalid paasword")
else:
    print(res)
    print ("Valid paasword")
```